# How (and where) can one change 'user@host $:' pattern in gnome-terminal?

Tags: command-line, bash, bashrc, prompt

When I start terminal in Ubuntu, I see:

```
ilya@HOST:~$
```

I need to add a timestamp to this, something like:

```
2011-10-09T09:32:00 ilya@HOST:~$
```

How can I configure this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a good [article](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-linux-unix-bash-shell-setup-prompt.html) about how to change your bash prompt and what all the special symbols (like \h) mean. It also has a link about how to change the colors in you prompt.

As far as applying the changes in your .bashrc, just run `source ~/.bashrc`

Answer (score 18):

Put this at end of your `~/.bashrc`

```
PS1="\D{%F}T\t $PS1"
```

Then restart your terminal.
For explanations, read manual page of bash, search for ^PROMPTING

(sorry, the first version of this answer reported erroneously single quotes instead of double)

Answer (score 3):

To apply the ~/.bashrc change type this inside the running terminal:

```
exec bash
```

No need to restart the terminal. This is useful for each change (in the terminal environment)

Answer (score 3):

I find that a great setup is to have 3 colourized groups:

- username & hostname
- current location
- current git branch

Plus a newline so you are back to the left side!

i.e.
[image]

You can have all this by having the following in your .bashrc file in your home directory.
Works for Unix and OS X

```
parse_git_branch () {
  git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/ (\1)/'
}
PS1='\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[01;33m\]$(parse_git_branch)\[\033[00m\]\n\$ '
```

If you want this plus your timestamps in four colors you can have:

```
$ PS1='\033[01;31m\] \D{%F} \t \[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[01;33m\]$(parse_git_branch)\[\033[00m\]\n\$ '
```

as in:

[image]

though personally I think I'll now go with:

```
parse_git_branch () {
  git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/\1/'
}
PS1='\033[01;31m\]\t\033[00m\]:'
PS1=$PS1'\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:'
PS1=$PS1'\[\033[01;34m\]\w\033[00m\]:\033[01;33m\]$(parse_git_branch)\[\033[00m\]\n\$ '
PS2='\[\033[01;36m\]>'
```

for

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To do this temporarily but immediately/on-the-fly, for example so that you can have some privacy while making a screencast, you can do the following

```
echo PS1='$\ ' > /tmp/ps1 && source /tmp/ps1 && rm /tmp/ps1
```

The PS1 variable sets the format, source applies that setting by reading from a file.

Now the command line looks like this:

```
$
```